# How to download selected multiple files as zip in SPFx development?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, feature

i am creating custom document library web-part, with the multiple file download functionality similar to the out-of-the box feature. how can we do that?

Comment: Similar thread is given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451856/how-can-i-let-a-user-download-multiple-files-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: those are mostly saying the window.open method, is there any way to get it download as zip like the default functionality